# How to access GNU-Emacs binaries located in HOME partition from everywhere?

Tags: installation, emacs, path

I built GNU-Emacs from scratch and now I have working binaries of it in my home partition. So `~/somedir/emacs/src` has all the binaries. If I issue the following:

```bash
PATH=$HOME/tmp/emacs/src:$PATH
```

that particular terminal-session can correctly access those binaries. I also added this to .profile and .bashrc so that every terminal instance is able to access them. Is there a way to make this a normal system app like others? I don't see the app listed in the app-list. I don't see it in the 'Open with' section of files. I am using MX GNU Linux distribution. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal system applications have typically their executable files in `/usr/bin` which is in your PATH by default. But this directory is usually reserved for executables brought by your distribution packages. `/usr/local/bin` is more adequate for add-ons.

But putting executable in this directory won’t make the program shown in your menus. Your should install a `.desktop` file like described in https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/ Note that you can have personal programs described by a `.desktop` file.